# Node memory is increasing on making requests

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a node app running on v8.11.2 and express ^4.14.0.

On making requests memory usage keep on going increase.

In server, I am using only for api calls, no other logic.

[image]

I am not able to understand, Why my react components are showing in the node memory.

Can any one please suggest me the better approach, how to handle these.
How to get rid of node memory holding React components.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those react components could have been created because of the server-side rendering.
Also Node has a garbage collector which removes unreferenced objects from the memory every once in a while (I oversimplified a bit). The situation you've described is not necessarily harmful, unless you have memory leaks. The trash icon in the developer console manually triggers garbage collection. If those objects remain in the memory after garbage collection it is likely that you have leaks. Unfortunately detecting leaks is one thing but finding the cause is a different matter and requires a lot of patience

Comment: Thanks @fardjad, but in my production server for every 50 requests 100 mb is go on increasing and stays at there. It is not decreasing. I am thinking this might be the issue. I have checked with another node js app in serverside rendering. But that app is not holding these components in memory.

Comment: If i restart the server then memory again starting from zero.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, for example as a minimal public github repo?